# Adding glassfish Server in Eclipse Kepler error

Tags: glassfish-4, eclipse-kepler

I am trying to add Glassfish-4 server to Eclipse in order to be able to run applications on this  server, but at the final step in "new Server" wizard, finished or next buttons are disabled and a message says: to enable Install Server, enter a path to a new directory..

The Glassfish server is found on the given path.

I can't add images because I don't have reputation, but here are the links:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=18yck1&s=5#.Umeq3vmnosY

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=13yezcm&s=5#.UmeqOPmnosY

Your help is apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a problem with your JDK...
I think you have to download a new JDK (jdk7) here:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

After you install it,

- Go to the 1st screen you have uploaded, and click "Installed JRE preferences"
- click "Add...", "Next", "Directory", and select the new JDK folder previously installed
- click "Finish"
- And return to the "New Server" screen, select the new JDK and it will works (it's working for me today).

Sorry for my english (I'm french ^^)

Regards,
Soufiane

Comment: You were right, that fixed the problem. I installed JDK EE from Oracle's website and it installed by default JDK into the glassfish folder so  I was trying to use that JDK. Now I have the glassfish server configured. Thanks a lot.