# Can't create glassfish server with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

My glassfish is running on localhost however when I try to create a glassfish server with eclipse next and finish buttons in the wizard are disabled.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19562842/3110505) is the same problem and the solution was to fix jdk. There is a link to Java se and I assume I need java ee. Anyway I have jdk1.7.0_55, jdk1.8.0 and jdk which is provided with glassfish but nothing works.

Could you give an advice about this issue?

System:

Glassfish 4.0

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Service Release 2

Build id: 20140224-0627

Windows 7 32-bit

[image: glassfishWizard1]
[image: glassfishWizard2]

UPD @JigarJoshi .log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-07-02 01:13:26.184
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 423; columnNumber: 42; Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.glassfish.tools.ide.server.parser.TreeParser.readXml(TreeParser.java:108)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassfishGenericServer.readServerConfiguration(GlassfishGenericServer.java:593)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassfishGenericServer.readDomainConfig(GlassfishGenericServer.java:221)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassfishGenericServer.validate(GlassfishGenericServer.java:320)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.ui.wizards.GFWizardCreation$Helper.validate(GFWizardCreation.java:410)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.ui.wizards.GFWizardCreation.enter(GFWizardCreation.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.TaskWizard.switchWizardFragment(TaskWizard.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.TaskWizardPage.setVisible(TaskWizardPage.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1259)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.access$4(WizardDialog.java:1238)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$8.run(WizardDialog.java:1227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 423; columnNumber: 42; Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.tools.ide.server.parser.TreeParser.readXml(TreeParser.java:103)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanLiteral(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    ... 71 more
```

Comment: _ but nothing works._ expand it

Comment: @JigarJoshi I mean buttons are still disabled.

Comment: how about finish button

Comment: @JigarJoshi Finish button work in Server Runtime Environment wizard but not on a Server wizard

Comment: oh. nevermind, is there anything useful in `eclipse.log` ?

Comment: looks like it attempts to read some xml file with `UTF-8` and the file isn't encoded in `UTF-8`