# I am not able to install the glassfish 4.0 server in eclipse kepler?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I have installed glassfish adapter and downloaded the glassfishserver 4.0,

I have followed the below steps ,
1)Go to Servers view, right-click with mouse and selected New → Server in contextual menu.

2)Choosed Glassfish 4 inside the available servers list

3)selected JDK and Run time name GlassFish 4.0 
 and gave already glassfish installed server path 
C:/glassfish4/glassfish4/glassfish  and got a message as "Found glassfish server version 4.0.0"

but still the next button is not enabled ?

Can anybody Please help me to install glassfish server with eclipse kepler?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a problem with your JDK... I think you have to download a new JDK (jdk7) here:

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
```

After you install it,

```
Go to the 1st screen you have uploaded, and click "Installed JRE preferences"
click "Add...", "Next", "Directory", and select the new JDK folder previously installed
click "Finish"
And return to the "New Server" screen, select the new JDK and it will works (it's working for me today).
```

[Adding glassfish Server in Eclipse Kepler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539735/adding-glassfish-server-in-eclipse-kepler-error)